# "Error:Attribute "style" has already been defined" error after adding facebook sdk from Maven

Tags: android, facebook, maven, gradle, android-studio

I added facebook SDK via maven in the following way:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
```

When I compile, I am getting the error on my `\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml` file as

`Error:Attribute "style" has already been defined`

Any Suggestions? It is very puzzling.

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.rayat.pricewiz'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/androidmvcframework.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.1.7@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
}
```

My colors.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="gray">#808080</color>
    <color name="grey">#CDCDCD</color>
    <color name="grey_dark">#5D5D5D</color>
    <color name="blue_light">#69b5ec</color>
    <color name="blue">#10a3d9</color>
    <color name="blue_dark">#295496</color>
    <color name="orange">#ed8305</color>
    <color name="orange_light">#F7BB31</color>
    <color name="logo_green">#46B525</color>
    <color name="green_menu">#0F6A15</color>
    <color name="orange_semi_transparent">#DC46B525</color>
    <color name="actionbar_text">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
    <color name="grey_border">#DDDDDD</color>
    <color name="navy_blue">#1A0DAB</color>
    <color name="background_tab_pressed">#6633B5E5</color>
    <color name="dark_grey">#808080</color>
    <color name="btn_unselected_grey">#FAFAFA</color>
    <color name="btn_unselected_grey_border">#EEEFF0</color>
    <color name="follow_unselected">#5D5D5D</color>
    <color name="bag_orange">#F7BB31</color>
    <color name="hint_color">#66000000</color>
    <color name="light_header_grey">#F1F1F1</color>
    <color name="grey_header_text">#5A5A5A</color>
    <color name="btn_pressed_color">#b3dae8</color>
    <color name="fragment_seperator">#e5e5e5</color>
    <color name="view_ontouch_color">#69B5EC</color>
</resources>
```

Thanks,

Noorul

Comment: most likely you have a duplicates of "style" inside the color.xml

Comment: Can you post your file ?

Comment: No I don't have style inside color.xml

Comment: May be there is a attribute named "style" in facebook sdk's color.xml.

Comment: I am getting Attribute "layout" has already been defined. on my colors.xml Don't know whats the real reason I was using the appCompat V21

Comment: Did you check the intermediate file yet ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Facebook SDK has an attribute named "style" and in my case it seems to be conflicting with the same attribute name in JazzyViewPager

Open the intermediate file in the build directory and search for "name=style" to find out where the problem is originating

The gradle error will show you the command line with the intermediate file name

Comment: Thanks, it was the JazzyViewPager that was making trouble.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! I wasted half of my day solving this. I had the same JazzyViewPager component in my project and was trying to integrate the Facebook sdk and the "style" attribute was giving me conflicts. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hi i am facing a same error well after reading comment i can't figure out what to rename can you please help...

Comment: Can you explain how come you can't find what to rename ?  did you open the directory and search for the text ?

Comment: I got it fixed by changing the name of the attribute inside JazzyViewPager.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My problem was with holographlibrary, which defines an "orientation" attribute that collided with GridLayout support library. Thanks for the orientation! Strangely, Android Studio located the error in colors.xml